# SQLIdentity Specification Changes After Replication

Tags: sql-server

I am a .net programmer with what I'd call a fair knowledge of SQL programming, and I use SQL heavily in my applications.  I'm not, however, a DBA and my knowledge there is somewhat limited so please pardon and correct any incorrect use of terminology, etc.

Simply put, we employ two separate SQL server 2005 setups that I'll call production and test. Every night, the records from the production system are replicated to (and overwrite) everything on the test system, so each day we start with a fresh copy of what's in production.

A great many of the tables on the production system have a sequence column (SEQ) with the Identity Specification set to Yes. These are all setup correctly and function perfectly.

After replication, however, the Identity Specification for the SEQ columns in the test system tables is set to No (the production tables are unaffected). This creates many headaches for programmers such as me as it results in many "Cannot insert the value NULL into column..." errors.

My approach thus far has simply been to use SSMS to change the Identity Specification to Yes, but the number of tables involved continues to increase and that's really becoming cumbersome to do everyday.

I'm now considering compiling the SQL change scripts for every table into a single large one and running that each day. The number of records in these tables is small enough (I think) that it wouldn't be a show-stopper; but, I really can't help but think that there is simply a setting in the replication logic that could be changed that will solve my problem at the source.

Is there? If not, any other suggestions?

Thanks for reading and please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Scott

Comment: Can you describe the replication process that you mention? Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Without knowing the mechanism by which your production tables are copied down to test, it's impossible to know why the identity property is being dropped along the way.

Comment: Sorry @Tim. SQL Server version is 2005. Replication is a snapshot publication if that helps.  I will try to collect more details on the replication itself and edit my post. If there are specific questions you have, let me know and I'll see what I can find. Unfortunately, I'm something of a messenger here which just adds to the frustration

Comment: Check if `NOT FOR REPLICATION` is set on identity columns on production.

Comment: Hi @dean.  NOT FOR REPLICATION is set to Yes on these columns.  I believe this is the correct approach since we want the Test records to be exact copies of the Production records (including the SEQ column).  Would this cause the Identity Specification to be set to No in Test after the replication?

Comment: It might. Could you change the snapshot replication properties to not recreate the tables, but rather truncate/delete?